# Wearing Tefillin over toupe

Tags: halacha, tefilin, hair

If someone wears a toupe which is only removed twice a month, is there any way to still get the mitzvah of wearing tefillin? Removing the toupe every morning to put in the tefillin would be an extreme burden and certainly too much to ask. So my real question is how bad is it to just make the bracha on the tefillin shel yad or even to make the bracha on shel rosh over the toupe?

Comment: See Igros Moshe OC 4:40:18 that would should not make a bracha with toupe on but at home without.

Comment: It is discussed [here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%D7%97%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.etzion.org.il/vbm/update_views.php?num=4031&file=/vbm/archive/beshiv/beshiv132.rtf&ei=liiWUbjtOqPw0gXTiYGQAQ&usg=AFQjCNFiZPitymoOGHjJ5sjYOdalQctPNw&bvm=bv.46471029,d.d2k)